# "Purimfest 1946" and the ten sons of Haman

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, purim

In the Megillah [(Esther 9:7)](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.9.7?lang=bi), the Torah lists the ten sons of Haman that were hanged.  If we look at the words, we notice that some letters are written small.For example, the "tav" in the name Parshandata is written as a small tav.

[image: Esther 9:7 from Sefaria.org]

[It is said](https://www.5tjt.com/hamans-sons-correlate-to-the-nuremberg-nazis-ys/) about Rabbi Michael Dov Weissmandl that he said:

> If this vav represents the sixth millennium of creation, and the other three smaller letters represent the years, the total is 5707; 5707 corresponds to the year 1946—the year that ten Nazis were hanged at the Nuremberg trials. Refer also to [here](https://www.thetorah.com/article/purimfest-1946-the-nuremberg-trials-and-the-ten-sons-of-haman).

Does anyone know where Rav Weissmandl said this? If he did not say this, are there sources (seforim, no newspapers) that discuss this exact idea?

Comment: I apologize for asking, but were the small letters used in editions of the Megillah prior to 1946?

Comment: @JBH I don’t know, but maybe someone found older editions of it?

Comment: @JBH refer to [here](https://www.textmanuscripts.com/medieval/book-of-esther-205507). As you can see in one of the pictures of that manuscript, the first name of the first son of Haman is written with a small "Tav". The manuscript of this megillas Esther is from around 1500.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *Ish Chamudos* (biography on the life of R' Michoel Ber Weissmandl, pg 282), this idea is quoted from R' Chaim Alexander Neiman, who claimed to hear it directly from R' Weissmandl.

[image: Ish Chamudos part 1]

The book quotes a number of further sources for the *remez* to *[gezeiras tach ve'tat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrdom_in_Judaism#:%7E:text=The%20Khmelnytsky%20Uprising%20was,killed%20by%20the%20Cossacks.)*. I have skipped to the relevant part:

[image: Ish Chamudos part 2]
[image: Ish Chamudos part 3]

It is clear from the footnote that this idea
was R' Weissmandl's own.

[image]

R' Yosef Chaim Ohev Tzion cites this idea too, and adds:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This idea from Rabbi Weissmandl does not appear in any of his writings.

According to [this article](https://www.thetorah.com/article/purimfest-1946-the-nuremberg-trials-and-the-ten-sons-of-haman), this claim is attributed to a variety of different people.

> In a letter to the newspaper Shearim, April 12, 1967,[21] Aharon
> Goldberger noted that the list of Haman’s ten sons (Esth 9:7–9)
> contain three letters that according to tradition are written in
> smaller script: tav, shin, zayin, whose numeric value in gematria is
> 707 (400+300+7). This, he argued, is a hidden reference to the Jewish
> year (5)707, during which the execution of the ten Nazi war criminals
> in Nuremberg took place.
>
> Goldberger writes that “unfortunately I do not remember who pointed
> this out to me.” While some attribute the teaching to R. Mordechai
> Schwab,[22] others to R. Aharon Rokeach[23] or R. Michael Ber
> Weissmandl,[24] the teaching is generally brought without any
> attribution.[25] The teaching gained prominence in the 1980s, with the
> publication of Nosson Munk’s article in the March 1986 issue of the
> American Orthodox magazine Jewish Observer as well as in two articles
> in the Israeli Charedi newspaper Yated Neʾeman (“The Faithful
> Peg”).[26]

See the footnotes in the article with expansive sources regarding the attribution to each of these Rabbanim - R' Mordechai Schwab, [R' Aharon Rokeach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Rokeach), or [Rav Weissmandl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dov_Weissmandl).

> Rabbi Michael Ber Weissmandl (1903–1957) was famous both for his
> rescue efforts during the Holocaust, and his teachings based on what
> would be later be termed Equidistant Letter Sequences (ELS), popularly
> known as “Bible codes.” For this attribution, see Alexander Firestein,
> Yalkut Divrei Assaf (Jerusalem: 2001), 46 [§16]; Moshe Menachem
> Ludmir, Yagdil Torah – Megillat Esther (Jerusalem: 2013), 75; R.
> Eliezer Ginzburg, Ginzei Hamelech on Megillat Esther (Brooklyn: 2000),
> 152, who says that “people say (אומרים)” it in the name of R.
> Weissmandl; Chaim Alexander Neiman, “Leika Midi d’Lo Remiza b’Orayta”
> [Wondrous Hints Regarding Events in the Holocaust Years], Or Yisrael
> 29 (Tishrei 5763/Sept 2002), 217. Yechiel Michel Stern, Otzar haYediot
> (Jerusalem, 2010), 2.172; Chaim Weissmandl, Ish Chanudot (Monsey:
> 2007), 281–282; Yosef Chaim Ohev Zion, Ata Baati (Jerusalem: 2014),
> 210. **Notably, the Nuremberg teaching does not appear in any of R. Weissmandl’s writings, and was first attributed to him in 2002.
> Nevertheless, R. Chaim Alexander Neiman wrote that Weissmandl taught
> him the Purim Code directly, saying that it was his idea**. While the
> Nuremberg teaching is not itself an example of ELS, it is often
> mentioned in the context of other “Bible codes,” and viewed as part of
> that genre. See for example Eran Ben Ezra, Sefer HaHochachot (Tel
> Aviv: 2014), pp. 126-130.

Comment: Interesting. I already linked to this page. So, can it be concluded that it is teaching unattributed? Is this teaching discussed in other sources?

Comment: I couldn't open your link. I assumed it was the same article as [this](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/1952332/hamans-sons-correlating-to-the-nuremberg-nazis-ys.html), which doesn't provide any sources.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the same, and from the same author.

Comment: In which case my link was [a different article](https://www.thetorah.com/article/purimfest-1946-the-nuremberg-trials-and-the-ten-sons-of-haman). You may find some of the sources quoted interesting.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is supposed to be in איש חמודות but I don't have that. Do you have any links or original texts that discuss it? I have trouble finding any of the mentioned seforim.

Comment: I found איש חמודות. I'll upload an image in an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152076/discussion-between-chortkov2-and-shmuel).